# Radio group in table layout with radio buttons aligned to columns

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-radiobutton

I am developing a feedback application which should has similar layout to this screen.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn3kh.jpg

I have designed the xml for layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.zankrutparmar.feedback.Frag_one">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/frag_one_title"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="819dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Poor"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Average"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Good"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Very Good"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Excellent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Theme &amp; Decor"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/poor1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_radio_poor"
            android:button="@null" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/average1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_radio_average"
            android:button="@null" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/good1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_radio_good"
            android:button="@null" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/very1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_radio_very_good"
            android:button="@null" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/excellent1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_radio_excellent"
            android:button="@null" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now whenever I want to apply margin to these radio buttons the center one remains in center and pushes all other buttons far.

I also tried the answers on this question [1]: [TableLayout of radiogroup(s) with respective label(s) aligned in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354562/tablelayout-of-radiogroups-with-respective-labels-aligned-in-android)

But in that layout the problem is all buttons in single row are getting selected. It means Radiogroup can't be placed in that layout.

And I have to fetch questions from a database and place them in my application.
So in Future I will have to add rows dynamically. 
Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to decrease your RadioButton layout_width and layout_height

Comment: I am using custom drawable as radio button background, So that width and height are mandatory. And I tried your answer but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I designed a new layout and fixed those previous issues. I am uploading that code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#8bae3a"
tools:context="com.zankrutparmar.feedback.Frag_two">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I'd use `android:gravity="center"`  and that fix my issue